# debugging javascript attached using bind or delegate

Tags: jquery, debugging

If javascript is attached to an event using bind or delegate (jquery), it isn't straightforward to debug which elements will respond to which event, not to know if theres anything attached to them.

Is there any tool that can help watch and debug the JS attached to events, the javascript runnning on a webpage as a whole ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the extension for firefox, FireQuery can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Firebug and the [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) extension.